# localizing an html document (hind sight)

Tags: php, html, localization

I am bulding a web application in PHP, which I have decided (far along the process) to have available in different languages.

My question is this:

I do not want to wade through all the HTMl code in the template files to look for the "words" that I need to replace with dynamically generated lang variables.

Is there a tool that can highlight the "words" used in the HTML to make my task easier.

so that when I scroll down the HTML doc, I can easily see where the language "words" are.

Normally when I create an app, I add  comments as i code, like below

```
 <label><!--lang-->Full Name</lable>
 <input type="submit" value="<!--lang-->Save Changes" name="submit">
```

so that when I am done, I can run through and easily identify the bits I need to add dynamic variables to....unfortunately I am almost through with the app (lost of HTML template files) and I had not done so.

I use a template engine (tinybutstrong) so my HTML is pretty clean (i.e. with no PHP in it)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way of doing that! You could use find and replace

Comment: @littleswany: XPath for the win!! getting comment nodes _is_ possible, not sure of comments in attribute values is valid markup, though

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, the comments in the value attribute are temporary. I only uses these as markers. When I do the actual translation they are removed.

Comment: @littleswany I normally would use a text editor like editplus for find and replace etc. but in this case i do not have the <!--lang--> comments in my html...so I am looking for some tool that can highlight the "text" strings in the html (so to speak)

Comment: @fredmarks: In that case: `$domDocument->getElementsByTagName('*');` + foreach over all the `DOMElement` instances + `$node->textContent` will give you what you're looking for. If some of the nodes are input tags, just use `$node->tagName` and switch to `$node->getAttributeNode('value')->value` to get the contents of those, just like I show in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, relatively easily even, using `DOMDocument` to parse the markup, `DOMXPath` to query for all the comment nodes, and then access each node's parent, extract the `nodeValue` and list those values as *"strings to translate"*:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($file);//or loadHTML in case you're working with HTML strings
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);//get XPath
$comments = $xpath->query('//comment()');//get all comment nodes
//this array will contain all to-translate texts
$toTranslate = array();
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    if (trim($comment->nodeValue) == 'lang')
    {//trim, avoid spaces, use stristr !== false if you need case-insensitive matching
        $parent = $comment->parentNode;//get parent node
        $toTranslate[] = $parent->textContent;//get parent node's text content
    }
}
var_dump($toTranslate);
```

Note that this can't handle comments used in tag attributes. Using this simple script, you will be able to extract those strings that need to be translated in the *"regular"* markup. After that, you can write a script that looks for `<!--lang-->` in tag attributes... I'll have a look if there isn't a way to do this using XPath, too. For now, this should help you to get started, though.

If you have not comments, other than `<!--lang-->` in your markup, then you could simply use an xpath expression that selects the parents of those comment nodes directly:

```
$commentsAndInput = $xpath->query('(//input|//option)[@value]|//comment()/..');
foreach ($commentsAndInput as $node)
{
    if ($node->tagName !== 'input' && $node->tagName !== 'option')
    {//get the textContent of the node
        $toTranslate[] = $node->textContent;
    }
    else
    {//get value attribute's value:
        $toTranslate[] = $node->getAttributeNode('value')->value;
    }
}
```

The xpath expression explained:

- `//`: tells xpath to search for nodes that match the rest of the criteria anywhere in the DOM
- `input`: literal tag name: `//input` looks for input tags anywhere in the DOM tree
- `[@value]`: the mentioned tag only matches if it has a `@value` attribute
- `|`: *OR*. `//a|//input[@type="button"]` matches links *OR* buttons
- `//option[@value]`: same as above: options with value attributes are matched
- `(//input|//option)`: groups both expressions, the `[@value]` applies to all matches in this selection
- `//comment()`: selects comments anywhere in the dom
- `/..`: selects the parent of the current node, so `//comment()/..` matches the parent, containing the selected comment node.

Keep working at the XPath expression to get all of the content you need to translate

## [Proof of concept](https://eval.in/185410)