# Find link from page code with preg_match

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, preg-match

I would like to change this using preg_match:

```
<li class="fte_newsarchivelistleft" style="clear: both; padding-left:0px;"><a class="fte_standardlink fte_edit" href="news,2480143,3-kolejka-sezonu-2014-2015.html">3 kolejka sezonu 2014/2015&nbsp;&raquo;&raquo;</a></li>
                      <li class="fte_newsarchivelistright" style="height: 25px;">komentarzy: <span class="fte_standardlink">[0]</span></li>
```

To this:

```
news,2480143,3-kolejka-sezonu-2014-2015.html
```

How can I do it? I'm trying with preg_match but that link is too complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_match` would indeed be too complicated. As stated on this site many times before: regex + HTML don't mix well. Regex is not suitable to process markup. A DOM parser, however is:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;//create parser
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);//create XPath instance for dom, so we can query using xpath
$elemsWithHref = $xpath->query('//*[@href]');//get any node that has an href attribtue
$hrefs = array();//all href values
foreach ($elemsWithHref as $node)
{
    $hrefs[] = $node->getAttributeNode('href')->value;//assign values
}
```

After this, it's a simple matter of processing the values in `$hrefs`, which will be an array of strings, each of which are the value of a `href` attribute.

Another example of using DOM parsers and XPath (to show you what it can do): [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567039/localizing-an-html-document-hind-sight/25567489#25567489)

To replace the nodes with the `href` values, it's a simple matter of:

- Getting the parent node
- constructing a text-node
- calling `DOMDocument::replaceChild`
- Finnishing up by calling `save` to write to a file, or `saveHTML` or `saveXML` to get the DOM as a string

An example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;//create parser
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);//create XPath instance for dom, so we can query using xpath
$elemsWithHref = $xpath->query('//*[@href]');//get any node that has an href attribtue
foreach ($elemsWithHref as $node)
{
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    $replace = new DOMText($node->getAttributeNode('href')->value);//create text node
    $parent->replaceChild($replace, $node);//replaces $node with $replace textNode
}
$newString = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: @user3898993: If ever you think of regex when processing markup, just remember: [it summons Cthulhu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)... it's a kind of legendary answer here :)